# Spinner text color and dropdown color are same

Tags: android, text, colors, background, spinner

I have 2 spinners in my activity. One of the spinners, comExpiry, is populated based on the value selected from another Spiner, comSpinner. However, I am running into a problem where comSpinner is properly displayed while comExpiry's both text and background color are being set to white in emulator running ICS, and hence are unreadable.

Please note that it works fine in both Froyo and Gingerbread. I noticed that the spinner is displayed as intended if I remove the listener attached to comSpinner. I have looked everywhere but can't find a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
comSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.watchListSpinnetComm);
comExpiry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.watchListSpinnerExpiry);

ArrayAdapter<String> expAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        McxCommApp.comSelect.get(0));
expAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
comExpiry.setAdapter(expAdapter);


myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, McxCommApp.comName);
myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

comSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
comSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new myListener());
```

ItemSelectedListener code is as follows:

```
public class myListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        expAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_a,
                McxCommApp.comSelect.get(pos));
        expAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        comExpiry.setAdapter(expAdapter);   
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

XML segment defining the layout:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/watchListTable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/watchListSpinnetComm"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/watchListSpinnerExpiry"
        android:layout_width="145dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/watchListAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="+"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</TableRow>
```